# PLS regression - My X and Y blocks are obtained at different sampling frequencies. Should I trim the X block or smooth and interpolate the Y block?

Tags: regression, sampling, frequency, partial-least-squares

PLS (partial least squares) regression is the tool that I'm using to express each Y block variable as a linear function of the X block variables. The overall goal of this project is to create a model that can predict the infrequently measured Y block parameters (once daily), from the frequently measured X block parameters (every minute). This would allow for more agile control of the Y block parameters based on the model predictions (or more likely, this would trigger an unscheduled measurement of Y to confirm that corrective action should be taken).

Consider the following properties of the Y block data:

- High measurement variability (only 1 measurement available from each daily sample, but according to the vendor the standard deviation of replicate measurements can be up to 30% of the average value)
- Low frequency signal
- Typically a monotonically decreasing function (and other measurements have obvious changes to determine when this assumption is invalid)
- X block values have a known linear dependence on the Y block values, and on other unmeasured parameters that vary independently of the Y block variables

As far as I'm aware, having more (useful) data in the model training step will decrease the magnitude of the error in future predictions. *I specifically want to know if it would be appropriate to generate a larger set of data to train the model with by interpolating new values for Y such that I have a value at every minute to align with the X block measurements.* I know this is generally frowned upon, but I feel that bullet points 2, 3 and 4 lend credibility to this kind of manipulation, but I can't find any references that discuss preprocessing the Y block parameters; all of the literature focuses on proper treatment of the X block data. I'm also curious if it would be appropriate to use a smoothing filter on the original Y data to account for the high measurement variability before interpolation.

I'd appreciate any insight one can offer into this problem. Also, I can't find anything in the literature about Y block preprocessing techniques,so I'd love a reference paper, or set of search terms, to be able to read more about it if possible.

Comment: Please give more background information about your goals. What is "PLS" regression? What are you trying to learn from your data? What are X block and Y block data?

Comment: I've added more background information to the original post about the overall project goal and what I'm specifically trying to improve by smoothing and interpolation of the data. PLS regression is a way to express Y=f(X), but the dependence of Y on X is determined in the dimensionally reduced score space. Essentially principal component analysis is applied to the X and Y blocks of data separately, with the added constraint that the covariance between X block scores and Y block scores is maximized.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Do you mean adding new data **artificially?** Also, preprocessing is generally OK as long as you can reverse it in the prediction step however you are already, by default, mean centering X and Y already. As I said, any manipulation on Y must be reversible. You can check if your pre-processing has an impact by cross-validation though that would only give you a small clue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by artificial. I do want to add data to my Y block that is determined computationally, instead of experimentally. I'm confident that the interpolated values will be accurate because the Y block varies very slowly and because it has a known trend from literature / prior internal experiments. I want to know if this interpolation will help prevent X block dependence on the unmeasured parameters from spuriously being attributed to the measured Y block variables because the unmeasured parameters vary independently of the Y block variables.

Comment: If you can interpolate goodly isn't that a model already? if you think the PLS will provide better results, I would argue that interpolation will provide any improvement at all.